# How does $\frac {(x^2 + 2x) - (a^2 + 2a)}{x-a}$ reduce to $x + a + 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, fractions

With the given function:

$$f(x) = x^2 + 2x $$

I am trying to evaluate the following expression:

$$\frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} $$

I've been informed that the solution is:
$x + a + 2$, where $x \ne a$

But I don't know how to get there. Can someone help me understand the logic behind the solution and where I'm going wrong? I hope this question is appropriate. It's my first on the site.

I started by replacing the functions with their bodies respecting the given inputs.

$$\frac {(x^2 + 2x) - (a^2 + 2a)}{x-a}$$

Then, it appears to me that one could factor out the X's and the A's.

$$\frac {x(x + 2) - a(a + 2)}{x - a} $$

At this point I'm actually stumped. I can see there's an $x$ and an $a$ with subtraction between them, but I don't see how they're related.

But given the solution, I guess the $x-a$ in the denominator cancels out the $x-a$ in the numerator (somehow?). Then I'd be left with

$$(x+2)+(a+2)$$

Adding this up I get $x+a+4$. I'm not sure what problems like these are called, so I'm not sure what to search to find what I'm missing.

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: hint: try grouping the terms as $(x^2-a^2) + (2x-2a)$. Do you see how you can continue from here?

Comment: Actually, the problem looks eerily similar to the definition of the derivative

Comment: Maybe try expanding -(exponent(a, 2)+2a).  Then you can factor out a.

Comment: except that it's not a limit

Comment: @Ani, your hint helped me to find the solution. Should I update my question? Or, post an answer, or something else?

Comment: @Jason you can update your question, or write up an answer to the post an accept it.

Comment: Note that technically, the function $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is not equal to $x+a+2$. The latter is defined for all values of $x$, while the former is not defined for $x=a$. They are only "equal" (take the same values) at $x\neq a$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my question.

Comment: Don't put the xs with the xs and the as with the a.  Try to factor out an $(x-a)$ term.  One trick is to note that $x^2 -a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)$.  So $\frac {(x^2+2x) - (a^2-2a)}{x-a}=\frac{(x^2-a^2)+(2x -2a)}{x-a} = \frac {(x-a)(x+a) + (2x-2a)}{x-a} = \frac {(x-a)(x+a)}{x-a} +\frac {2x-2a}{x-a}$.  Does that help.

Comment: @fhhh The jargon is that for $x\ne a$ the fraction is a secant gradient, while the $x\to a$ limit of it, the derivative, is a tangent gradient. (Of course, you're not supposed to be thereby reminded of two trigonometric functions.)

Comment: @fleablood, yes that does help. This is exactly what I was missing. Once Ani, gave me the hint, I was able to find what you've shown in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\frac {x(x + 2) - a(a + 2)}{x - a} $$

You got so close:

$$\frac {x^2 - a^2+2x-2a}{x - a} $$

Then you just need to know $x^2-a^2=(x+a)(x-a)$.

More generally $x^n-a^n=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+...+a^{n-1})$. This formula is used all over the place in maths. You can see it's true by considering what happens if you put $x=a$ into $x^n-a^n$.

Comment: Yes! An earlier comment lead me to see that I could have done the grouping of terms in a different way. Then, as you pointed out, we can see the difference of squares and can factor out the $(x - a)$ on both sides of the addition.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(x^2+2x)-(a^2+2a)}{x-a} = \frac{(x^2-a^2)+2(x-a)}{x-a}=\frac{(x+a)(x-a)+2(x-a)}{x-a}=\frac{(x-a)[(x+a)+2]}{x-a} = x+a+2,\;\; \text{if $x\neq a$}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac {(x^2 + 2x) - (a^2 + 2a)}{x-a} =\frac {x^2 -a^2 + 2x-2a}{x-a}=\frac {(x+a)(x-a) + 2(x-a)}{x-a}=$$

$$=\frac {(x+a)(x-a) }{x-a}+\frac {2(x-a)}{x-a}=x+a+2$$

for $x\neq a$, the key point it to recognize that $x^2-a^2=(x+a)(x-a)$.

As an alternative we can proceed using that

$$x^2  +2x-a^2-2a=0 \implies x=\frac{-2\pm \sqrt{4-4(-a^2-2a)}}{2}=-1\pm(a+1)$$

and therefore, since $u=-a-2$ and $v=a$ are roots for the polynomial

$$x^2 +2x-a^2-2a=(x-u)(x-v)=(x+a+2)(x-a)$$

---

Another way by long division

\begin{array}{rrr|ll} 
x^2 & +2x & -a^2-2a   & x  -  a
\\   -x^2 & +ax &  &  &   x +a+2
\\ \hline     & (a+2)x & -a^2-2a
\\&-(a+2)x & a^2+2a & & & & 
\\ \hline & 0&  0  \end{array}

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your second approach.  I learn a lot by reading your answers.

Comment: Thanks! I don’t think I can teach you anything in math but I appreciate a lot your advice and your kindness! Bye